# Safe to delete "node_modules" for an API-only app?

Tags: jhipster

I generated a microservice app using JHipster. My understanding is that this is only a REST API and does not include any kind of UI. My plan is to create a separate project for an Angular app, which will use this API.

Do I still need the "node_modules" directory in my microservice app? Can I just delete it?

Comment: I think in your API some part of may use the node_module that's why I refer please don't delete it.

Answer (score 4):

As you generated a microservice, you should have a package.json file with only generator-jhipster dependency. It's here to allow you to create entities with the exact same version of JHipster you used to generate your microservice.

So you can safely delete the node_modules folder. It won't impact your build.
If one day you need to generate entities, simply launch yarn install or npm install to have back your node_modules folder.

Comment: I know node_modules is a "cache" with the packages needed by node.js component. But, a API-only microservice what do with node_modules ? Is same component in JHipster 7 microservices that use node.js ?